# Avoiding fullscan on query

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

Through this query

```
SELECT * FROM
      (SELECT
          T.*,
          'T'||to_char(min(T.ORDEN_CAMPO) OVER (PARTITION BY T.NOMBRE_ESQUEMA, T.NOMBRE_TABLA, T.CONDICION_ADICIONAL ORDER by T.ORDEN_CAMPO)) ALIAS1
       FROM SOLICITUDES.TBL_QRY_DINAMICO_SOLDEU T
       WHERE
          TIPO_QRY = 'SOLICITUD_DEU' AND
          SUBTIPO_QRY = Numero_Seccion_in
       )
   ORDER BY  ORDEN_CAMPO
```

I get a TABLE FULL SCAN when executing an explain plan. Specifically on the part where the over partition is done. Is there any other way to do the same logic?

In the outside select statement if I call directly which values I want to get ,I don't get TFS but when I call ALIAS1 ,TFS appears.

Comment: do you have index on ORDEN_CAMPO ?

Comment: is there a special need for the outer query? the order by could be added to the inner query. Regarding the full table scan, that's one of the fastest operations and you're basically asking the database to look at all the rows in that table. You could add a trigger but depending on the table size and data distribution, it might not improve the performance. If you need to access a significant chunk of data from that table, it's actually faster to use the full table scan instead of the index.

Comment: btw. you do not need `ORDER by T.ORDEN_CAMPO` when selecting the MIN OVER PARTITION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. index the column ORDEN_CAMPO
2. what is the share of rows filtered by `TIPO_QRY = 'SOLICITUD_DEU' AND SUBTIPO_QRY = Numero_Seccion_in`? If less than 10%, index both columns.
3. you can try to index the columns NOMBRE_ESQUEMA, NOMBRE_TABLA and CONDICION_ADICIONAL

Note: as @xionutz2k already mentioned, full table scan can be in some situations more effective than index scan. If you have all indexes mentioned and the explain plan always shows full table scan, then it is OK.